# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord' / how to switch python versions

Tags: python, discord

I'm sorry that this has already been asked, but I have not found anything helpful.

I am trying to create a discord bot and am following YouTube videos.

When I try to run my code, I keep getting the error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'
despite having installed discord and discord.py.

I checked where it has been asked before and some people have said that using older Python versions makes it work, but newer ones don't. Why not? How can I use an older Python version without ruining the latest one?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is missing a few details: did you install the discord module?

Comment: I don't understand? I did the pip install discord thing in terminal if that's what you meant?

Comment: Hey, your question is asking a lot of things at once. Better you can share the URL for the video you are following and point to the timestamp and if possible  you can share the output   of  'pip list'  , So people can understand your issue

Comment: @BiswajitMohanty it's relatively straightforward so far. All I've done at the moment is pip install discord and then written some very basic code, but that's not what is giving me the error.

Comment: See if this resolves your issue "pip install discord.py"  for python3, 

reference: https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/

Comment: @BiswajitMohanty thanks. tried that and it didn't help anything though.

Comment: Yeah, kinda weird issue you got mate, 
only one more thing I can ask you to see if you have enough permission to pip install on your particular path, try with Sudo or have virtualenv install and try 

I tried on python 3.9.6 , it worked well. 

regarding using an older version of python : 
you can use pyenv or virtualenv to create multiple python environments to use as per your choice

Comment: @BiswajitMohanty thanks man i'll try it and let you know.

Comment: @theparrot97 Which os are you using? (Linux/MacOS/Windows)

Comment: @TobiasWilfert MacOS

Comment: @theparrot97 are you using an IDE to run your python code or do you run it in the terminal? It seems like you did install discord but possibly on the wrong location.

Comment: @TobiasWilfert Spyder. I'll try reinstalling and running in terminal.

Comment: @theparrot97 Try running your code via the terminal if you installed the discord via the terminal. For example 'python filename' or 'python3 filename'.

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me and none of my modules worked.
uninstall python and then reinstall it; so that it is updated.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: there's no code involved? it's just reinstalling python

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried `pip install discord` and `pip install discord.py`?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Yes I did. Neither changed anything.

Comment: then i dont know